# How to send only "work" related requests over vpn for El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: macbook-pro, network, macos, vpn

I have configured a new VPN connection (Type - Cisco IPSec) for work using network preferences and it works.

How can I stay connected to my `work vpn` and direct only my `work traffic` through vpn? 
Given that I already know that all of my work related requests fall under specific ip-range say, `10.0.0.0/8`, how can I direct my non-work web traffic to not use the work vpn?

If possible, please provide an effective way to verify the setup as well.

Comment: Related and potential answer: http://superuser.com/questions/4904/how-to-selectively-route-network-traffic-through-vpn-on-mac-os-x-leopard

Comment: ^^ tried that already. Doesn't help

Answer (score 1):

You should talk to the VPN administrator.  Typically, the decision about what traffic is routed to your network is made by the VPN server since there are security implications to allowing the device to send only some traffic down the tunnel.  We use Cisco VPN and we do not allow clients to do what you describe because it opens a potential hole in our network security.